# Input column based values in a row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table as follows:

```
home         visitor      home_goal    v_goal    tot_goal
Arsenal      Liverpool      0            2          0
Arsenal      Chelsea        1            1          0
Leeds City   Arsenal        0            1          0
```

I would like to find out the total goals scored by Arsenal. To do so, I would like to find

1. the value in `home_goal` if Arsenal is the value in `home`
2. the value in `v_goal` if Arsenal is the value in `visitor`

The column `tot_goal` should reflect this outcome. For eg, the final data frame should look like so:

```
    home         visitor      home_goal    v_goal    tot_goal
    Arsenal      Liverpool      0            2          0
    Arsenal      Chelsea        1            1          1
    Leeds City   Arsenal        0            1          1
```

Is the way i mentioned the correct way to go about the problem? I do not want to create a subset due to space constraints. I would like a command that would get me the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ifelse`.

If your `dataframe` is `df`:

```
df$tot_goal<-ifelse(df$home=="Arsenal",df$home_goal,df$v_goal)
```

Comment: `ifelse(test, yes, no)`, more detils in `?ifelse`